# Overwrite api platform generated client

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm toying with api platform and just saw that it comes with a client generator command.

When I run it a second time it has no effect because files have already been generated.

But, in the case of a custom template, if I want to re-run the client generation but want to achieve an update is there anything I can do?

At the moment the only way that I have found is to delete the directories created and run the command, but it is not e nice solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client generator is designed for scaffolding only. It is intended to bootstrap your project, then it will never try to update the existing code.

> At the moment the only way that I have found is to delete the directories created and run the command, but it is not e nice solution..

It's the only solution for now. We may introduce a new `--overwrite` flag (Pull Request welcome), but internally it will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: After spotting your profile I guess I have to accept your answer :)

Comment: What could be used as pure API Client that reads the generated docs?